# Связь моделей в EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Есть две модели:

```
public class User : IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; } = "user";
    public List<RefreshToken> RefreshTokens { get; set; }
}

public class RefreshToken : IEntity
{       
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Token { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset Expiration { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

Несмотря на то, что навигационное свойство есть, FK есть, когда я пытаюсь посмотреть _context.Users.RefreshTokens, там нет ничего. Не понимаю, вроде ведь все правильно? Почему тогда null?

Update:

По всей видимости не хватает Include в запросе, поэтому попробовал добавить, но выглядит ужасно, можете посоветовать, как исправить? Или лучше так не делать, отказаться от навигационных свойств и просто делать поиск по таблице токенов через `Where(p => p.UserId == user.Id)`?

```
var userTokens = _libraryContext.Users.Where(p => p.Login == username)
    .Include(p => p.RefreshTokens);
var savedRefreshToken = userTokens.Select(p => p.RefreshTokens)
    .Select(t => t.Where(p => p.Token == requestModel.OldRefreshToken)
    .FirstOrDefault()
    .FirstOrDefault()
    .Token;
```

Два `FirstOrDefault()` здесь потому что после первого возвращается `IEnumerable<RefreshToken>`, а после второго - непосредственно `RefreshToken`.

Comment: В БД связи созданы? Каким кодом вы извлекаете данные?

Comment: @tym32167 да, foreign key проставлены в коде таблиц. Обновил вопрос, посмотрите, пожалуйста

Comment: На какой части кода у вас падает? `FirstOrDefault()` может вернуть null, если коллекция пустая.

Comment: @tym32167 с Include не падает, теперь уже вопрос в том, адекватное ли это решение или, может, есть что-то лучше? Хочу качественный код писать сразу просто, и меня смущают как-то эти лямбды в лямбде и довольно большое выражение в целом

Comment: `var token = _libraryContext.RefreshTokens.Where(x=>x.User.Login == XXX && x.Token == YY).Select(x=>x.Token).FirstOrDefault();` ?

Comment: @tym32167 да уж, не додумался до того, что можно было через RefreshTokens.User вытаскивать свойства, а не упираться в List<RefreshToken>. Спасибо большое, можете написать как решение, я отмечу верным!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В большинстве случаев имеет смысл обратиться к той сущности, которую вы хотите в итоге получить

```
var token = _libraryContext.RefreshTokens
                    .Where(x=>x.User.Login == XXX && x.Token == YY)
                    .Select(x=>x.Token)
                    .FirstOrDefault();
```